# Mango search in Arrays

Tags: arrays, couchdb, selector, couchdb-mango

My document has a structure like this:

```
{
  "Calibration": {
    "Presettings": {
      "Date": [
        {
          "Value": "2016-09-02 10:11",
          "Type": "generated"
        },
        {
          "Value": "2016-09-05",
          "Type": "schedule",
          "Duration": "5"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How must I define the selector part of a query object to get all documents with dates (Value) less or equal to a given date and with `Type=='generated'`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, you need to create your index. I suggest that you create an index on the `Calibration.Presettings.Date field`.

You can use the following JSON object to create it:

```
{
  "index": {
    "fields": [
      "_id",
      "Calibration.Presettings.Date.[].Type"
    ]
  },
  "type": "json"
}
```

So the selector would be like this :

```
{
  "selector": {
    "Calibration.Presettings.Date": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "Type": "generated"
          },
          {
            "Value": {
              "$gte": "2016-09-01"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We execute the query on the field *Calibration.Pressettings.Date* which is an **Array**. Since it's an array, we have to use the *$elemMatch* operator.

Then, we have a **$and** condition for the Value and the Type.

The **Type** of the **Date** has to be *generated*. With can either use the **$eq** operator or simply use this simple syntax:  `{"field":"value"}`.

Finally, the Date`s Value must be greater or equal to X date. We can use the **$gte** operator.

Comment: Many thanks. This helps and I understand much more than before.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it helped you. It may help others in the futur

Comment: Where did you find documentation for the notation used to index arrays? In my own tests the index is never used in the query.

Comment: I used [cloudant](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#query) documentation which is pretty similar to CouchDB. I know that there are some bugs with index selection with CouchDB 2.1. Perhaps you should post another question or create an issue on the Couch repo

Comment: When I do that my answer in the selector query is: "warning": "no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time" ¿so what is wrong?

Comment: It means that the query planner can't find an index usable for your query. Either your query is too complex or the index wrong.

Comment: This query will work, but like @Sam and Julian pointed out, I don't think that the index will be used.  
Quoting the [Cloudant documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-query#selector-basics) : _« However, for IBM Cloudant Query indexes of type json, you can't use "combination" or "array logical" operators [...], Only the equality operators such as $eq, $gt, $gte, $lt, and $lte - but not $ne - can be used as the basis of a more complex query. »_
For this index to work you'll need to use "text" indexes, or create a view that emit a key for each element of the array.