# Couchdb Mango Query selector on object in array of objects

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, couchdb-mango

I have a couch db filled with entries in this form

```
{
  ...
  "templates" :[
    {"template_id":"1"}
    {"template_id":"2"}
    {"template_id":"3"}
  ]
}
```

I am trying to write a mango query that will find all entries that have templates that contains an object with a specific template_id. I know that it is possible with views but I want to use a mango query if possible

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892556/mango-search-in-arrays-couchdb) should help you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try the $elemMatch operator in Mango Query selector. This operator "*returns all documents that contain an array field with at least one element matching the supplied query criteria*"

This selector will retrieve any document that contains template_id:1 in the templates array

```
  {
    "templates": {
      "$elemMatch": 
        {"template_id":"1"} 
    }
  }
```

The elemMatch operator accepts a selector expression so you can write more complex queries.

```
 {
    "templates": {
      "$elemMatch": {"$or":[
        {"template_id":"1"},
        {"template_id":"3"}
        ]
      }
  }
```