# cloudant search query with logical NOT to exclude specific value

Tags: cloudant

I have a requirement to capture likes or dislikes on news. I am storing it in Cloudant DB with news details and users who liked and disliked.

```
{ "id":"news-001" dislike:[ 'user@gmail.com'] }
```

I am capturing 1000's of news articles. I need a search index so that i can filter for specific user who disliked the articles during search result itself rather than manually checking for user email in my loop code. 

I tried multiple options since Cloudant does not support to use of logical NOT alone. Please suggest options

Comment: So you are looking for a single user's email in an array of emails?

Comment: Are you having a separate `document` for each user email or are you having all user emails in a single document in an `array`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd need to create an index of users from the `dislike` array and then search on that.

The answer to this question should help you with querying on an array: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892556/mango-search-in-arrays-couchdb
stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892556/mango-search-in-arrays-couchdb%20stackoverflow.com)